# Installing Roccat Tyon driver and libgaminggear

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to install the drivers and the gui for my roccat tyon gaming mouse. In the install file, it says I need libgaminggear. I downloaded that and opened that install file. I ran the commands it says to run and created the build file. It then makes me run `make` which returns `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` I decided to skip ahead and created the groups it needed. It then asks me to make a file at `/etc/modules-load.d/uinput.conf with either uinput or uhid as it's content.` What does this mean? Just make the folders and files empty except for one line with uinput?

I went back to the roccat install file and did everything up to the `make` commands, where again it returned an error. Why do I get these errors? What do I do about the files? Sorry, I'm very new to Ubuntu and this whole installing packages thing (previous windows user).

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: ppa:  https://launchpad.net/~berfenger/+archive/ubuntu/roccat

Comment: I got that downloaded, now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You need three steps:

1. add ppa with *roccat-tools* to your system :

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:berfenger/roccat
   ```
2. resynchronize the package index files from their sources:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. install *roccat-tools* (with libgaminggear as dependency):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install roccat-tools
   ```

Now you can find *roccat-tools* in dash search